# Unable to deserialiaze Jaxrs response entity get

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

im using below code

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

     WebTarget webTarget = client.target(uri);
                 Builder builder = webTarget.request();
     Response response = builder.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(Response.class);

    final List<MyResponse> accountList = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<MyResponse>>(){});
```

**This returns accountList but all the values inside the list Objects were **null** ie(Each property value inside MyResponse object is null)

But If i use below code

```
String myResponse = response
                        .readEntity(String.class);
             ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
             mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
             MyResponse[] obj = mapper.readValue(myResponse, MyResponse[].class);
```

**obj returns the proper array of Objects..but i dont want to read as string and deserialize**..Please suggest!

Uri response is as follows

```
[
{
        "type": "A1",
        "attrs": {
            "test_card": "Y"
        }

    }, {
        "type": "A2"
        "attrs": {
            "issue_card": "N"
        }
    }
]
```

MyResponse Object

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyResponse implements  Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("type")
    private String Type;

    @JsonProperty("attrs")
    private MyAttributes myAttributes;


    public MyAttributes getattrs() {
        return myAttributes;
    }

    public void setattrs(MyAttributes myAttributes) {
        this.myAttributes = myAttributes;
    }

    public MyResponse() {
    }

    public String gettype() {
        return Type;
    }

    public void settype(String Type) {
        this.Type = Type;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, obj);
    }

}
```

MyAttributes Object

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyAttributes implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4************;

    @JsonProperty("test_card")
    private String testCard;



    public DecisionActionAttributes() {
    }


    public String getNewCardInd() {
        return testCard;
    }

    public void setNewCardInd(String testCard) {
        this.testCard = testCard;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this, false);
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
    }
```

Comment: What is it you are actually asking?

Comment: There is a mismatch in your question. Inside `MyResponse` class you have a field of type `MyResponseAttributes` but this class is missing in your question.

Comment: Chewtony: question is why object property values inside accountList were null ..instead I should get the values mentioned in uri response